# Is the replica set heartbeat frequency or timeout period configurable?

Tags: mongodb

All replica set members monitor all the other members by sending out a heartbeat every 2 seconds. These requests will time out after 10 seconds.

Are these two values configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at MongoDB 2.2.0, the answer is currently "These values are not configurable at runtime".  You could possibly check out the code from [github.com/mongodb/mongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo) and modify the values yourself, but this may have unexpected side effects.

Fortunately there is work underway to add configurable timeout/heartbeat settings for the next iteration of MongoDB (2.3.x dev/unstable which will eventually culminate in the 2.4 production/stable release).

See [SERVER-1929](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1929) in the MongoDB issue tracker for more information.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently possible using the function `rs.reconfig()`  after versions 3.0. or the command replSetGetConfig.settings.heartbeatTimeoutSecs.

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/rs.reconfig/#rs.reconfig

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/replSetGetConfig/#dbcmd.replSetGetConfig

You can see in the httpinterface:

mongohost:mongoport/replSetGetConfig?text=1

under settings how much time is the heartbeat timeout in secs

```
"settings" : { "chainingAllowed" : true,
      "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
      "getLastErrorModes" : {},
      "getLastErrorDefaults" : { "w" : 1,
        "wtimeout" : 0 } } }
```