# Resync a Mongo Replica Set

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a replica set, and to free some disk space, I want to resync my replica set members.

Thus, on the `SECONDARY` member of the replica set, I've emptied the `/var/lib/mongodb/` directory which holds the data for the database.

When I open a shell to the Replication Set, and execute the command `rs.status()`, the following is showed.

```
{
    "set" : "rs1",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-13T08:28:00.414Z"),
    "myState" : 5,
    "term" : NumberLong(29),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "10.20.2.87:27017",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 5,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 148,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(6363490787761586, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(29)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-12-13T07:54:16.000Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "configVersion" : 3,
            "self" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.20.2.95:27017",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 146,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(6363490787761586, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(29)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-12-13T07:54:16.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-12-13T08:27:58.435Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-12-13T08:27:59.447Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(6363486827801739, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-12-13T07:38:54.000Z"),
            "configVersion" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "10.20.2.93:30001",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 146,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-12-13T08:27:58.437Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-12-13T08:27:59.394Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "configVersion" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Why does my secondary member shows `Could not find member to sync from, however, my primary is up and running."

My collection is sharded, over 6 servers, and I have this message on 2 replica set members. The ones which have the `SECONDARY` member on top in the `members` array when requesting the replication set status.

I really would like to get rid of this error message.
It scares me :-)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it was due to the fact that the heartbeat timeout was too short, you can solve that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768807/is-the-replica-set-heartbeat-frequency-or-timeout-period-configurable)